# How does the function passed to create server Return Object

Tags: node.js

I have just started with Node.js.While learning to write a simple node.js code that outputs hello world to the browser I used the following code. In this code the listen method is called upon the argument passed on the createServer method.Here are my doubts

1.The Function does not seem to create any Object.

2.How can we call methods on response we haven't defined any.

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request,response))
{
response.writeHead(200,"Content-Type":"text/plain");
response.write("Hello World");
response.end()
}).listen(8888);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I believe you misplaced the parentheses. The code should be:

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (request,response) {
response.writeHead(200,"Content-Type":"text/plain");
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

Secondly, the function that you write (that accept request and response as arguments) is called a callback function. The createServer function will call this function, passing 2 arguments to it - request and response.
That's why you can use response and request when defining it.